# Building a simple counter app using react-native and redux, but each time counter increments, console log prints out counter * 2 times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Am I doing something wrong?

Basically, you press text on one scene, and the next scene shows the current value of count.  Each time you click the text on Page One, count is incremented by 1.

However, each time I log `this.props`, i see that it logs it the same number of times as my current count.

```
//   src/index.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import * as actionCreators from './actions';
import configureStore from './store/configure-store';

import PageOne from './test/page-one';
import PageTwo from './test/page-two';

const store = configureStore();

const RouterWithRedux = connect(
  state => ({
    count: state.counter.count
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
  }))(Router);

export default class Root extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux>
          <Scene key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
            <Scene key="pageOne" component={PageOne} initial={true} title="PageOne"/>
            <Scene key="pageTwo" component={PageTwo} title="PageTwo" />
          </Scene>
        </RouterWithRedux>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

.

```
//   src/actions/counter.js
export const TYPES = {
  INCREMENT: 'INCREMENT',
  DECREMENT: 'DECREMENT'
};

export function increment() {
  return {
    type: TYPES.INCREMENT
  };
}

export function decrement() {
  return {
    type: TYPES.DECREMENT
  };
}
```

.

```
//   src/reducers/counter.js
import { TYPES } from '../actions/counterActions';

const initialState = {
  count: 0
};

export default function counter(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TYPES.INCREMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + 1
      };
    case TYPES.DECREMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count - 1
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

.

```
//   Page One
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

class PageOne extends Component {

  goToPageTwo() {
    Actions.pageTwo();
    this.props.actions.increment();
  }

  render() {
    console.log('page one', this.props);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text onPress={this.goToPageTwo.bind(this)}>This is PageOne!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({ count: state.counter.count}))(PageOne);
```

.

```
//   Page Two
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

class PageTwo extends Component {

  // componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  //   console.log('next props', nextProps.count);
  // }

  render() {
    console.log('page two', this.props);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text onPress={Actions.pageOne}>The current count is {this.props.count}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({ count: state.counter.count}))(PageTwo);
```

Can someone help me understand this?  here's a link to my repo for the full code: https://github.com/281330/counter

Comment: Could you add just the code relevant for this problem please?

Comment: sure.  sorry about that.  adding it in now!

Comment: Are you sure `this.props.actions.increment()` isn't throwing an error? You have a `mapDispatchToProps` setup in your top level component, but not in the connected component that actually calls it

Comment: Hmm.  It isn't throwing any errors.  I thought normally when using redux, you would connect your top level component and the state and actions would be passed down to the child components.

Comment: If you put a console log inside the action creator does it get hit when you click the button? or in the switch case statement of your reducer?

Comment: @azium yes it is.  http://imgur.com/AlLieNs